# PubNub not publishing from Service

Tags: android, service, pubnub

I've previously used PubNub from a background service to publish location updates on android. I wish to use it for a different project and wrote a simple service to test the new API. However, publishing always fails and I am unable to pinpoint why.

Here is the service code:

```
public class MessageService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MessageService";
    private PubNub pubnub;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public MessageService() {
        PNConfiguration config = new PNConfiguration();
        config.setPublishKey("pub_key_removed_for_privacy");
        pubnub = new PubNub(config);
    }

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pubnub.publish()
                    .channel("demo")
                    .message("hello from service")
                    .async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                            if (status.isError()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Publish failed");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Publish successful");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        timer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    private final IBinder binder = new ServiceBinder();

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public MessageService getService() {
            return MessageService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity, I simply call startService() and watch the logs and I always get the failure message. I do have the internet and network_state permissions in my manifest and can't think of any other reasons why this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CraigConover Can you post this as an answer so I may mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Subscribe Key is Always Required

You are initializing PubNub with only the publish key. The [subscribe key is always required when you config/init PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android/api-reference-sdk-v4#configuration), even if you are only going to publish.

If you do not init with a subscribe key, or it is invalid (typo or disabled) then you will get a `400 - Invalid Subscribe Key error` response when you try to execute a PubNub operation (`subscribe`, `publish`, `history`, etc.)

```java
public MessageService() {
    PNConfiguration config = new PNConfiguration();
    config.setPublishKey("your-pub-key");
    config.setSubscribeKey("your-sub-key");
    pubnub = new PubNub(config);
}
```